# The equivalent of start-stop-daemon for RedHat 6

Tags: rhel, upstart, start-stop-daemon

I have an upstart script to create a service in RedHat 6:

```
env PLAY_BINARY=/usr/bin/play
env HOME=/opt/warda
env USER=root
env GROUP=root

[...]

script
    exec start-stop-daemon --start --exec $PLAY_BINARY --chuid $USER:$GROUP --chdir $HOME --start $HOME
end script
```

In Ubuntu everything goes right.

However in RedHat, when I launch `sudo initctl start play`, I get a successful feedback `play start/running`, but `play` doesn't run.

I think that the problem is that `start-stop-daemon` doesn't exist in RedHat.

How can I replace the `exec start-stop-daemon...` command?

Comment: Are you using RedHat 6 or RedHat 7?

Comment: If you are using RedHat 7, it will be better to read the docs and create a `systemd-unit`

Comment: I'm using RedHat6

Comment: No one solution for RedHat6? :(

Comment: for RHEL6 you will need to create and install a traditional sysV init script.  Then you can user /etc/init.d/play stop/start or /sbin/service stop/start play etc. and /sbin/chkconfig play on/off to enable/disable it at boot time.

Answer (score 6):

You could try the `daemonize` command, which is available from the EPEL repository. It seems to do most of what you require here.